# Watch instructions from executable?

Tags: c++, executable

Is it possible for someone to 'watch' how your variables/etc are assigned at runtime after you've deployed your executable and dependency files? More specifically, can someone 'watch' how you are managing your internal data if they have your executable?

I don't want to know how to do this, I just want to know if it is possible. Whether it is or isn't will determine how I structure my code.

Comment: On Linux you can use the `ptrace` system call to trace a program's execution one instruction at a time. It's the heart of any *debugger*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but there are varying levels of difficulty. If you give them a debug build, it could be pretty easy for them to launch your executable in a debugger and then just use their debugging tools to watch the execution (just like programmers do when they develop).

If you give them a stripped but not optimized build, then they don't have all the debug symbol names but they can still load your program in a debugger and watch it execute, instruction by instruction and map out what memory is being used and how. It's more difficult, but still possible.

If you give them a stripped, optimized build, it's a bit harder (as the optimizer can produce some complex and hard to follow assembly) but still not impossible.

It's always possible, in the end. Whether or not it's worth someone's time and effort, though, is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's entirely possible. Any decent debugger can follow your code.

And no, this should **not** determine how you structure your code, because I can guarantee that no matter what you do will affect whether someone else can understand/follow your code. It may slow someone not so clever down, but there are some REALLY clever people out there, whose entire life revolves around understanding other people's compiled code.